# Apache FOP in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xslt, apache-fop

I am writing some XML -> PDF generating templates in Apache FOP for an asp web app. I need to use Visual Studio for my development. Visual studio has great editing and auto complete for regular XSL, I was wondering if there  is any way to add this functionality for FOP tags. 
At least is there a way to stop it from thinking the file is hopelessly broken due to the  tags?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FO namespace must be added to the file.

```
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
```

This does not give auto complete, but will stop the file from preventing the project from building.